# SoapUI - How to use Property Transfer with POST request

Tags: json, post, soapui

I am starting to evaluate SoapUI as my test suite, but the Property Transfer thing is really holding me back. I've read a lot of articles about it, but I could not find a way to make it work in my case.

My source is a POST request. This POST request returns me a JSON. I need to pass one of the values of this JSON to the next test.

My response is this:

```
<Response xmlns="https://localhost/authorize">
    <access_token>4a00c67e</access_token>
   <refresh_token></refresh_token>
   <scope>auth</scope>
   <token_type>online</token_type>
</Response>
```

I need to get the `<access_token>` and pass it to the next test as a parameter.

What should I write in the SOURCE and TARGET boxes to get this to work? Why is it so complicated and why there is no easy to understand tutorial about this? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do that, for me, was using "Property: Response" and "Path Language: JSONPath".

Then for the source I used simply "$.access_token"

For the Target, I defined a Property called access_token in the Project.

Answer (score 8):

To add to what Abhishek said. If you only need the access_token you would use the following XPath:

```
declare namespace var="https://localhost/authorize";
//var:Response/var:access_token
```

Comment: it is not required to declare namespace. Instead we can just use //*:access_token if soapUI complains when namespace is missing.

Comment: Interesting, that I did not know. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

In the property transfer step you source would be the step from where you want to get the data, in the source property select response.

In the space below source put `//access_token` this will extract the value of the access_token and make it available for transfer. if you do not provide the xpath soapUI will provide the whole response xml for transfer.

Your target would be the step where you want to set the extracted property, `<access_token>` in your case. The property would be the property to which you want to set the extracted value.

**Important** place your property transfer step after the source step. Execution in soapUI is top down and if property transfer is placed before the source step you will not have any value to transfer.

To give you an example
[image: soapUI property transfer step]

In this example i have a test request called `SourceRequest` whose response will be transferred to a test suite level property called aa.
As you can see here. I have given my property transfer a name `PropertyTransferName`(it can be anything you want). In the source I have mentioned my source request and property as Response. As I am going to save the whole response in a test suite level property, I have mentioned my test suite as the target and given the name of the property to which i want to transfer.

In this i could have parsed the response of my source property by giving an xpath like you need to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek. However, I need to use only the `<access_token>`, not the whole response. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: yep like i mentioned in my post...in the space under source and above target put //access_token

Comment: I couldn't make it work with just //access_token whereas it should work according with XPath. It worked when I used namespaces though.

Comment: try //*:access_token that'll make it work without specifying the namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

For the "Source" x-path use:

```
**//*[local-name()='access_token']**
```

select "**Transfer text content**"

select "**Use XQuery**"

This should extract the text content from your access_token node.

Comment: Almost perfect, I had to use //*[local-name()='access_token'] and ResponseAsXml as pointed in @Hina answer, but the other options are correct, thanks

Answer (score -1):

To transfer property, it is important to know whether the response type (from where you are transferring value) is json or xml. In case it is json, as in screenshot below:

[image]

make sure to set property as "ResponseAsXml" in transfer property window as below:

[image]

else "Response" will do the needful.