# How select json value in soapui property transfer from HTTP request?

Tags: json, rest, properties, soapui, transfer

Here is a raw response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 08:46:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)

{"id":"myId"}
```

I tried to set Property (source is response from another test step, property can be Request, Response etc.) Response and ResponseAsXML and for both I can not extract value. And try xPath selection but it does not work.
Is it possible to extract `id` from HTTP response with json?

**UPDATED**

If I select ResponseAsXml I get the following string:

```
[<Response xmlns="http://localhost/path">
   <id>882fe993-d150-b67c-4b0f-014931e2dd21</id>
</Response>]
```

I have tried xPath:

```
declare namespace sam="http://localhost/path";
//sam:response
```

Also I wrote `//sam:Response` or `//response` result is `[null]` string.

Comment: Do you have some code to show? This should be trivial with ResponseAsXml.

Comment: I tried with it, but result always `[null]`. I have tried to use xPath as in examples in soapui.

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Answer (score 6):

Within REST Request, we get a response which is a JSON Object:

[image: Rest Request with a JSON Object response]

and when we want to transfer this response with Property Tranfer: we can leave Source text field empty and we will tranfer the whole JSON object, if we want to tranfer a data of this object which is in this case **name** we set the source text field **$.name** and we are now able to retrieve a specific data of the JSON object.

[image: Retrieve JSON Data within Property Transfer]

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me as in the comment for this answer: [SoapUI - How to use Property Transfer with POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239246)

You can simply use:

```
//*:id
```